# how to print the list value of the nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I have created the following dictionary:

```
Book_list={
 'Fiction': {1001: ['Pride and Prejudice', 'available'],
             1002: ['Fahrenheit 451', 'available']},
 'Horror': {2001: ['House of leaves', 'available'],
            2002: ['The Shinking', 'available']}}
```

now I want to store the status that is "available" in a variable with its key so that it can be used further for delete or update.

So the output I mean is like:

```
status={1001:available,1002:available,2001:available,2002:available}
```

Please help me by telling that how could I get this output.

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: is the second list item always the availability? Can the outer dict layer ('fiction') be discarded?

Comment: Your sample data should include a case where a key should NOT be selected and also  cases where the same year appears in two categories with all, none or a mix of 'available' are present.  This would clarify your objective from the expected output (which you would need to adjust accordingly).  Also, have you tried anything ?

Comment: @MichaelButscher no I haven't tried anything yet as I got stuck here and I am new to coding so was confused with the same.

Comment: @MartijnVanAttekum yes the Fiction part is important as going further I want the keys to delete list in it. I am creating a library management system(as a initial coder) where Fiction, Python ,Horror and Math are the type of books and under it 1001,1002...so on are the book id which have values as book name and its availability status

Comment: @AlainT. I haven't tried anything yet but through this given "status dictionary" I want to first check if particular book is available or not and if available I want to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
rs = {ii : status for category in Book_list.values()  for ii, (name, status) in category.items() if status == "available"}
print(rs)
```

**Output**

```
{1001: 'available', 1002: 'available', 2001: 'available', 2002: 'available'}
```

The above is *equivalent* to the followings nested for loops:

```
for category in Book_list.values():
    for ii, (name, status) in category.items():
        if status == "available":
            rs[ii] = status
```

For understanding the unpacking expressions such as:

```
# _, category
# ii, (name, status)
```

you could read this [link](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/). For a general introduction to Python's data structures I suggest reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
def receive_available_books(Book_list):
    status = {}
    for cat in Book_list.values():
        for code, book  in cat.items():
            status[code] = book[1]
    return status
```

Output:
`{1001: 'available', 1002: 'available', 2001: 'available', 2002: 'available'}`

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.10's structural pattern matching, maybe not super appropriate/helpful for this, but I just wanted to try it :-)

```
rs = {}
for category in Book_list.values():
    for item in category.items():
        match item:
            case ii, [_, 'available' as status]:
                rs[ii] = status
```

(code adapted from Dani's)

Answer (score 0):

With this code you get almost exactly the output you want:

```
d={}
for a in Book_list.values():
    for x,y in a.items():
        d[x]=y[1]
print("status=", d)
```

You could also, of course, assign `d` to your a `status` variable.

This code just creates first an empty `d` as dict and then fills it with data and finally prints it. To fill `d` with data, `a`, `x` and `y` take different values while walking (iterating) over your object:

- `a`: For example `{1001: ['Pride and Prejudice', 'available'], 1002: ['Fahrenheit 451', 'available']}`
- `x`: For example `1001`
- `y`: For example `['Pride and Prejudice', 'available']`

  - `y[1]` would then be `'available'`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).